# Unable to add custom queue to audio_service 0.8.0 flutter for android

Tags: flutter, audio, service

I wanted to view an example of how to add a custom queue to the Audio service. I am returning a JSON that has a list of music. But I am unable to add this to the audio service background and run it. Please help.
This is an example of my player class.
The songModel Has all the song data
The code below is my implementation.

```
`import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'Songs.dart';
import 'backgroundTask.dart';

class Player extends StatefulWidget {
  SongModel songModel;
      Player({@required this.songModel});
  @override
  _Player createState() => _Player();
}

class _Player extends State<Player> {
  static SongModel data;
   List<MediaItem> songs;
  @override
  Future<void> initState()  {
    super.initState();
    data = widget.songModel;
    songs = data.songs;
    print(songs);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder<ScreenState>(
        stream: _screenStateStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final screenState = snapshot.data;
          final queue = screenState?.queue;
          final mediaItem = screenState?.mediaItem;
          final state = screenState?.playbackState;
          final basicState = state?.basicState ?? BasicPlaybackState.none;
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(data.currentSong.title),
              Text(data.songs.length.toString()),
              Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                if (queue != null && queue.isNotEmpty)
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous),
                        iconSize: 64.0,
                        onPressed: mediaItem == queue.first
                            ? null
                            : AudioService.skipToPrevious,
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next),
                        iconSize: 64.0,
                        onPressed: mediaItem == queue.last
                            ? null
                            : AudioService.skipToNext,
                      ),
                      if (mediaItem?.title != null) Text(mediaItem.title),
                    ],
                  ),
              ]),
              if (mediaItem?.title != null) Text(mediaItem.title),
              if (basicState == BasicPlaybackState.playing)
                RaisedButton(child: Text("Pause"), onPressed: pause)
              else if (basicState == BasicPlaybackState.buffering ||
                  basicState == BasicPlaybackState.skippingToNext ||
                  basicState == BasicPlaybackState.skippingToPrevious)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 64.0,
                    height: 64.0,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                )
              else if (state != BasicPlaybackState.stopped)
                RaisedButton(child: Text("Stop"), onPressed: stop),
              RaisedButton(child: Text("Play"), onPressed: play),
              RaisedButton(child: Text("StartService"),onPressed:()=> start(data.songs))
            ],
          );
        },
      )),
    );
  }


}


 _backgroundTaskEntrypoint(){

  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());
}

start(data) {
  AudioService.start(
    backgroundTaskEntrypoint:_backgroundTaskEntrypoint,
    androidNotificationChannelName: 'com.zimosound_app.us',
    notificationColor: 0xFF2196f3,
    androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher',
    enableQueue: true,
  );
  AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(data);
  print(AudioService.queue);
}







stop() => AudioService.stop();

play() async {
  if (await AudioService.running) {
    AudioService.play();
  }
}

pause() => AudioService.pause();

Stream<ScreenState> get _screenStateStream =>
    Rx.combineLatest3<List<MediaItem>, MediaItem, PlaybackState, ScreenState>(
        AudioService.queueStream,
        AudioService.currentMediaItemStream,
        AudioService.playbackStateStream,
        (queue, mediaItem, playbackState) =>
            ScreenState(queue, mediaItem, playbackState));

class ScreenState {
  final List<MediaItem> queue;
  final MediaItem mediaItem;
  final PlaybackState playbackState;

  ScreenState(this.queue, this.mediaItem, this.playbackState);
}
`
```

THis is My background audio class

```
    import 'dart:async';

import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

MediaControl playControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_play_arrow',
  label: 'Play',
  action: MediaAction.play,
);
MediaControl pauseControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_pause',
  label: 'Pause',
  action: MediaAction.pause,
);
MediaControl skipToNextControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_skip_next',
  label: 'Next',
  action: MediaAction.skipToNext,
);
MediaControl skipToPreviousControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_skip_previous',
  label: 'Previous',
  action: MediaAction.skipToPrevious,
);
MediaControl stopControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_stop',
  label: 'Stop',
  action: MediaAction.stop,
);


final prevControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_stop',
  label: 'Stop',
  action: MediaAction.stop,
);

class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  var _queue = AudioService.queue;
  int _queueIndex;
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
  Completer _completer = Completer();
  BasicPlaybackState _skipState;
  bool _playing;

//  AudioPlayerTask(List<MediaItem> queue, int queueIndex){
//    this._queue = queue;
//    this._queueIndex = queueIndex;
//  }

  bool get hasNext => _queueIndex + 1 < _queue.length;

  bool get hasPrevious => _queueIndex > 0;

  MediaItem get mediaItem => _queue[_queueIndex];

  BasicPlaybackState _eventToBasicState(AudioPlaybackEvent event) {
    if (event.buffering) {
      return BasicPlaybackState.buffering;
    } else {
      switch (event.state) {
        case AudioPlaybackState.none:
          return BasicPlaybackState.none;
        case AudioPlaybackState.stopped:
          return BasicPlaybackState.stopped;
        case AudioPlaybackState.paused:
          return BasicPlaybackState.paused;
        case AudioPlaybackState.playing:
          return BasicPlaybackState.playing;
        case AudioPlaybackState.connecting:
          return _skipState ?? BasicPlaybackState.connecting;
        case AudioPlaybackState.completed:
          return BasicPlaybackState.stopped;
        default:
          throw Exception("Illegal state");
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onStart() async {
    var playerStateSubscription = _audioPlayer.playbackStateStream
        .where((state) => state == AudioPlaybackState.completed)
        .listen((state) {
      _handlePlaybackCompleted();
    });
    var eventSubscription = _audioPlayer.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
      final state = _eventToBasicState(event);
      if (state != BasicPlaybackState.stopped) {
        _setState(
          state: state,
          position: event.position.inMilliseconds,
        );
      }
    });
   // AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(_queue);
    await onSkipToNext();
    await _completer.future;
    playerStateSubscription.cancel();
    eventSubscription.cancel();
  }

  void _handlePlaybackCompleted() {
    if (hasNext) {
      onSkipToNext();
    } else {
      onStop();
    }
  }

  void playPause() {
    if (AudioServiceBackground.state.basicState == BasicPlaybackState.playing)
      onPause();
    else
      onPlay();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onSkipToNext() => _skip(1);

  @override
  Future<void> onSkipToPrevious() => _skip(-1);

  Future<void> _skip(int offset) async {
    final newPos = _queueIndex + offset;
    if (!(newPos >= 0 && newPos < _queue.length)) return;
    if (_playing == null) {
      // First time, we want to start playing
      _playing = true;
    } else if (_playing) {
      // Stop current item
      await _audioPlayer.stop();
    }
    // Load next item
    _queueIndex = newPos;
    AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    _skipState = offset > 0
        ? BasicPlaybackState.skippingToNext
        : BasicPlaybackState.skippingToPrevious;
    await _audioPlayer.setUrl(mediaItem.id);
    _skipState = null;
    // Resume playback if we were playing
    if (_playing) {
      onPlay();
    } else {
      _setState(state: BasicPlaybackState.paused);
    }
  }

  @override
  void onPlay() {
    if (_skipState == null) {
      _playing = true;
      _audioPlayer.play();
      AudioServiceBackground.sendCustomEvent('just played');
    }
  }

  @override
  void onPause() {
    if (_skipState == null) {
      _playing = false;
      _audioPlayer.pause();
      AudioServiceBackground.sendCustomEvent('just paused');
    }
  }

  @override
  void onSeekTo(int position) {
    _audioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: position));
  }

  @override
  void onClick(MediaButton button) {
    playPause();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    await _audioPlayer.stop();
    await _audioPlayer.dispose();
    _setState(state: BasicPlaybackState.stopped);
    _completer.complete();
  }

  void _setState({@required BasicPlaybackState state, int position}) {
    if (position == null) {
      position = _audioPlayer.playbackEvent.position.inMilliseconds;
    }
    AudioServiceBackground.setState(
      controls: getControls(state),
      systemActions: [MediaAction.seekTo],
      basicState: state,
      position: position,
    );
  }

  List<MediaControl> getControls(BasicPlaybackState state) {
    if (_playing) {
      return [
        skipToPreviousControl,
        pauseControl,
        skipToNextControl,
        stopControl,
      ];
    } else {
      return [

        skipToPreviousControl,
        playControl,
        skipToNextControl,
        stopControl,
      ];
    }
  }

  @override
  void onAudioBecomingNoisy() {
    playPause();
  }

  @override
  void onAudioFocusGained() {
    playPause();
  }


  @override
  void onAudioFocusLost() {
    playPause();
  }

  @override
  void onAudioFocusLostTransient() {
    playPause();
  }

  @override
  void onAudioFocusLostTransientCanDuck() {
    playPause();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar issue and am parsing JSON files with song data to form a queue from them. This is what I've found so far.

As I understand it, only the `BackgroundAudioTask` class should make calls to `AudioServiceBackground`, and your UI works through `AudioService` to perform said calls. That being said, I haven't been able to get the queue to work all that well. What I've done is initialized the queue with a local mp3 of 2 seconds of silence, and then added songs to the queue with the following (just a tacky workaround, but seems to work at the moment):

```
MediaItem myMediaItem = new MediaItem(...);
queue.add(myMediaItem);
AudioService.updateQueue(queue);
AudioService.addQueueItem(myMediaItem);
```

I think this works because this way the media item is added to both the main and background isolate. It's not the greatest, but it works. I call in my `StreamBuilder<ScreenState>` function for as many items I add to the queue, but to be sure it's not too much I only do 10-20 at a time, only when the current `MediaItem` being played is within 5 from the last items in the queue.

Hope this helps, good luck.

Also worth mentioning, you should be overriding functions like `onUpdateQueue` in the `BackgroundAudioTask` class you define. That’s a crucial element to getting your queue to update properly.