# In flutter how can we use audio_service to fetch dynamic data

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
 await AudioService.start(
      backgroundTaskEntrypoint: _audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint,
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio Player',
      androidNotificationColor: 0xFF2196f3,
      androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher',
      params: getParams(),
    );
```

This is my code snippet where i am calling AudioService.start but i am unable to start service.
i am fetching the audio item from firebase and want to load those as a list view to audio_service..But i am unable to do that.My class where i have defined a audio service extending the background service.

```
import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

MediaControl playControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_play_arrow',
  label: 'Play',
  action: MediaAction.play,
);
MediaControl pauseControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_pause',
  label: 'Pause',
  action: MediaAction.pause,
);
MediaControl skipToNextControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_skip_next',
  label: 'Next',
  action: MediaAction.skipToNext,
);
MediaControl skipToPreviousControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_skip_previous',
  label: 'Previous',
  action: MediaAction.skipToPrevious,
);
MediaControl stopControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_stop',
  label: 'Stop',
  action: MediaAction.stop,
);

class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  //
  var _queue = <MediaItem>[];

  int _queueIndex = -1;

  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
  AudioProcessingState _skipState;
  bool _playing;

  bool get hasNext => _queueIndex + 1 < _queue.length;

  bool get hasPrevious => _queueIndex > 0;

  MediaItem get mediaItem => _queue[_queueIndex];

  StreamSubscription<AudioPlaybackState> _playerStateSubscription;
  StreamSubscription<AudioPlaybackEvent> _eventSubscription;

  @override
  void onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    print("-------------------------------------started");
    _queue.clear();
    List mediaItems = params['data'];
    for (int i = 0; i < mediaItems.length; i++) {
      MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromJson(mediaItems[i]);
      _queue.add(mediaItem);
    }
    _playerStateSubscription = _audioPlayer.playbackStateStream
        .where((state) => state == AudioPlaybackState.completed)
        .listen((state) {
      _handlePlaybackCompleted();
    });
    _eventSubscription = _audioPlayer.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
      final bufferingState =
      event.buffering ? AudioProcessingState.buffering : null;
      switch (event.state) {
        case AudioPlaybackState.paused:
          _setState(
              processingState: bufferingState ?? AudioProcessingState.ready,
              position: event.position);
          break;
        case AudioPlaybackState.playing:
          _setState(
              processingState: bufferingState ?? AudioProcessingState.ready,
              position: event.position);
          break;
        case AudioPlaybackState.connecting:
          _setState(
              processingState: _skipState ?? AudioProcessingState.connecting,
              position: event.position);
          break;
        default:
      }
    });
    AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(_queue);
    onSkipToNext();
  }

  @override
  void onPlay() {
    if (_skipState == null) {
      _playing = true;
      _audioPlayer.play();
    }
  }

  @override
  void onPause() {
    _playing = false;
    _audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  @override
  void onSkipToNext() async {
    skip(1);
  }

  @override
  void onSkipToPrevious() {
    skip(-1);
  }

  void skip(int offset) async {
    int newPos = _queueIndex + offset;
    if (!(newPos >= 0 && newPos < _queue.length)) {
      return;
    }
    if (null == _playing) {
      _playing = true;
    } else if (_playing) {
      await _audioPlayer.stop();
    }
    _queueIndex = newPos;
    _skipState = offset > 0
        ? AudioProcessingState.skippingToNext
        : AudioProcessingState.skippingToPrevious;
    AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    await _audioPlayer.setUrl(mediaItem.id);
    print(mediaItem.id);
    _skipState = null;
    if (_playing) {
      onPlay();
    } else {
      _setState(processingState: AudioProcessingState.ready);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    _playing = false;
    await _audioPlayer.stop();
    await _audioPlayer.dispose();
    _playerStateSubscription.cancel();
    _eventSubscription.cancel();
    return await super.onStop();
  }

  @override
  void onSeekTo(Duration position) {
    _audioPlayer.seek(position);
  }

  @override
  void onClick(MediaButton button) {
    playPause();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onFastForward() async {
    await _seekRelative(fastForwardInterval);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onRewind() async {
    await _seekRelative(rewindInterval);
  }

  Future<void> _seekRelative(Duration offset) async {
    var newPosition = _audioPlayer.playbackEvent.position + offset;
    if (newPosition < Duration.zero) {
      newPosition = Duration.zero;
    }
    if (newPosition > mediaItem.duration) {
      newPosition = mediaItem.duration;
    }
    await _audioPlayer.seek(_audioPlayer.playbackEvent.position + offset);
  }

  _handlePlaybackCompleted() {
    if (hasNext) {
      onSkipToNext();
    } else {
      onStop();
    }
  }

  void playPause() {
    if (AudioServiceBackground.state.playing)
      onPause();
    else
      onPlay();
  }

  Future<void> _setState({
    AudioProcessingState processingState,
    Duration position,
    Duration bufferedPosition,
  }) async {
    print('SetState $processingState');
    if (position == null) {
      position = _audioPlayer.playbackEvent.position;
    }
    await AudioServiceBackground.setState(
      controls: getControls(),
      systemActions: [MediaAction.seekTo],
      processingState:
      processingState ?? AudioServiceBackground.state.processingState,
      playing: _playing,
      position: position,
      bufferedPosition: bufferedPosition ?? position,
      speed: _audioPlayer.speed,
    );
  }

  List<MediaControl> getControls() {
    if (_playing) {
      return [
        skipToPreviousControl,
        pauseControl,
        stopControl,
        skipToNextControl
      ];
    } else {
      return [
        skipToPreviousControl,
        playControl,
        stopControl,
        skipToNextControl
      ];
    }
  } this is my class
}

class AudioState {
  final List<MediaItem> queue;
  final MediaItem mediaItem;
  final PlaybackState playbackState;

  AudioState(this.queue, this.mediaItem, this.playbackState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should overrid`this method in`AudioPlayerTask` class:

```
  @override
  // ignore: missing_return
  Future<Function> onAddQueueItem(MediaItem mediaItem) async{
    // queue.add(mediaItem); or somthing like this to update your queue
    await AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(queue);
    try {
      await _player.load(ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        children:
        queue.map((item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.id))).toList(),
      ));
      // In this example, we automatically start playing on start.
      onPlay();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      onStop();
    }
  }
```

Then you can call this function in your UI:

```
await AudioService.start(
                        backgroundTaskEntrypoint: audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint,
                        androidNotificationChannelName:
                            'Audio Service Demo',
                        // Enable this if you want the Android service to exit the foreground state on pause.
                        //androidStopForegroundOnPause: true,
                        androidNotificationColor: 0xFF2196f3,
                        androidNotificationIcon: 'mipmap/ic_launcher',
                        androidEnableQueue: true,
                      );
// call this func:
await AudioService.addQueueItem(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the author [here](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/8#issuecomment-450768392) the plugin originally didn't allow passing any arguments to the background task directly. It was designed to let the background task internally query what to play from internal storage via SQLite or tools like `shared_preferences`.

However today, the plugin allows to pass media data down to the background task via 3 different ways that I identified:

- `AudioService.addQueueItem(item)` combined with `onAddQueueItem` as mentioned in the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65578502/797639) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62648705/797639)
- `AudioService.customAction('url', url)` combined with `onCustomAction` as explained [here](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/8#issuecomment-451044737)
- Use the `Map<String, dynamic> params` argument of the `AudioService.start` method. It is received as an argument of the background task's `onStart` method as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65180411/797639)