# How to find the current song duration in Flutter with audio_service and just_audio

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, just-audio

The when you set the `MediaItem` in [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) you don't know the song duration yet because [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) hasn't had a change to tell you at this point.

The [FAQs](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-update-an-existing-mediaitem) say to update the `MediaItem` like this:

```dart
modifiedMediaItem = mediaItem.copyWith(duration: duration);
AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(modifiedMediaItem);
```

But it is unclear to me how or where to do this. The [example app in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/tree/master/example) sidesteps this problem by providing precomputed times. ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/543))

How and where do I transfer the duration from just_audio to audio_service so that it can update the listeners?

*I found something that works so I'm adding an answer below.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have your [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) `AudioPlayer` set up, you can listen for changes in the duration stream and then make the updates there:

```dart
_player.durationStream.listen((duration) {
  final songIndex = _player.playbackEvent.currentIndex;
  print('current index: $songIndex, duration: $duration');
  final modifiedMediaItem = mediaItem.copyWith(duration: duration);
  _queue[songIndex] = modifiedMediaItem;
  AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(_queue[songIndex]);
  AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(_queue);
});
```

**Notes**:

- This is inside your [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) `BackgroundAudioTask` class.
- When I tried using `_player.currentIndex` directly I was getting strange behavior (the first two songs both had index `0` before the index started incrementing) ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/255)). That's why I use the playback event here to get the current index.
- For my example I'm using a `List<MediaItem>` for the queue. I didn't actually need to use the setQueue in the final line because by UI wasn't listening for changes in the queue, but I suppose it's good to do anyway.

### Fuller code example

Here is my whole `background_audio_service.dart` for reference. It's an adaptation of the [documentation example](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart):

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

void audioPlayerTaskEntrypoint() async {
  AudioServiceBackground.run(() => AudioPlayerTask());
}

class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  AudioPlayer _player = new AudioPlayer();
  AudioProcessingState _skipState;
  StreamSubscription<PlaybackEvent> _eventSubscription;

  List<MediaItem> _queue = [];
  List<MediaItem> get queue => _queue;

  int get index => _player.playbackEvent.currentIndex;
  MediaItem get mediaItem => index == null ? null : queue[index];

  @override
  Future<void> onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    _loadMediaItemsIntoQueue(params);
    await _setAudioSession();
    _propogateEventsFromAudioPlayerToAudioServiceClients();
    _performSpecialProcessingForStateTransistions();
    _loadQueue();
  }

  void _loadMediaItemsIntoQueue(Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    _queue.clear();
    final List mediaItems = params['data'];
    for (var item in mediaItems) {
      final mediaItem = MediaItem.fromJson(item);
      _queue.add(mediaItem);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _setAudioSession() async {
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration.music());
  }

  void _propogateEventsFromAudioPlayerToAudioServiceClients() {
    _eventSubscription = _player.playbackEventStream.listen((event) {
      _broadcastState();
    });
  }

  void _performSpecialProcessingForStateTransistions() {
    _player.processingStateStream.listen((state) {
      switch (state) {
        case ProcessingState.completed:
          onStop();
          break;
        case ProcessingState.ready:
          _skipState = null;
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _loadQueue() async {
    AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(queue);
    try {
      await _player.load(ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        children:
            queue.map((item) => AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(item.id))).toList(),
      ));
      _player.durationStream.listen((duration) {
        _updateQueueWithCurrentDuration(duration);
      });
      onPlay();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
      onStop();
    }
  }

  void _updateQueueWithCurrentDuration(Duration duration) {
    final songIndex = _player.playbackEvent.currentIndex;
    print('current index: $songIndex, duration: $duration');
    final modifiedMediaItem = mediaItem.copyWith(duration: duration);
    _queue[songIndex] = modifiedMediaItem;
    AudioServiceBackground.setMediaItem(_queue[songIndex]);
    AudioServiceBackground.setQueue(_queue);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onSkipToQueueItem(String mediaId) async {
    final newIndex = queue.indexWhere((item) => item.id == mediaId);
    if (newIndex == -1) return;
    _skipState = newIndex > index
        ? AudioProcessingState.skippingToNext
        : AudioProcessingState.skippingToPrevious;
    _player.seek(Duration.zero, index: newIndex);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onPlay() => _player.play();

  @override
  Future<void> onPause() => _player.pause();

  @override
  Future<void> onSeekTo(Duration position) => _player.seek(position);

  @override
  Future<void> onFastForward() => _seekRelative(fastForwardInterval);

  @override
  Future<void> onRewind() => _seekRelative(-rewindInterval);

  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {
    await _player.dispose();
    _eventSubscription.cancel();
    await _broadcastState();
    await super.onStop();
  }

  /// Jumps away from the current position by [offset].
  Future<void> _seekRelative(Duration offset) async {
    var newPosition = _player.position + offset;
    if (newPosition < Duration.zero) newPosition = Duration.zero;
    if (newPosition > mediaItem.duration) newPosition = mediaItem.duration;
    await _player.seek(newPosition);
  }

  /// Broadcasts the current state to all clients.
  Future<void> _broadcastState() async {
    await AudioServiceBackground.setState(
      controls: [
        MediaControl.skipToPrevious,
        if (_player.playing) MediaControl.pause else MediaControl.play,
        MediaControl.skipToNext,
      ],
      androidCompactActions: [0, 1, 2],
      processingState: _getProcessingState(),
      playing: _player.playing,
      position: _player.position,
      bufferedPosition: _player.bufferedPosition,
      speed: _player.speed,
    );
  }

  /// Maps just_audio's processing state into into audio_service's playing
  /// state. If we are in the middle of a skip, we use [_skipState] instead.
  AudioProcessingState _getProcessingState() {
    if (_skipState != null) return _skipState;
    switch (_player.processingState) {
      case ProcessingState.none:
        return AudioProcessingState.stopped;
      case ProcessingState.loading:
        return AudioProcessingState.connecting;
      case ProcessingState.buffering:
        return AudioProcessingState.buffering;
      case ProcessingState.ready:
        return AudioProcessingState.ready;
      case ProcessingState.completed:
        return AudioProcessingState.completed;
      default:
        throw Exception("Invalid state: ${_player.processingState}");
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my state management class I got a stream from `AudioService` like this:

```dart
Stream<AudioPlayerState> get mediaStateStream =>
    Rx.combineLatest2<Duration, MediaItem, AudioPlayerState>(
        AudioService.positionStream,
        AudioService.currentMediaItemStream,
        (position, mediaItem) => AudioPlayerState(position, mediaItem.duration));
```

where AudioPlayerState is

```dart
class AudioPlayerState {
  const AudioPlayerState(this.currentTime, this.totalTime);
  final Duration currentTime;
  final Duration totalTime;

  const AudioPlayerState.initial() : this(Duration.zero, Duration.zero);
}
```

And I used a `StreamBuilder` in the Flutter UI to listen to `mediaStateStream` and update my audio player seek bar widget.

Comment: Hi is it possible to provide a github link for this project?

Comment: @dorado, I don't currently have a public example on GitHub but I'm working on an article about audio_service that will include an example. Follow me on Twitter or Medium to get updates. https://suragch.dev

Comment: That's awesome. Will add you on twitter. Thanks!

Comment: @dorado https://suragch.medium.com/background-audio-in-flutter-with-audio-service-and-just-audio-3cce17b4a7d

Comment: Hi, can you update this code to work with audio_service 0.18 ? I followed the migration guide but my player notifications are black and the duration is not updating correctly

Comment: @Suragch can you please help?

Comment: @AsjadSiddiqui, I'm sorry. I do hope to update [my tutorial](https://suragch.medium.com/background-audio-in-flutter-with-audio-service-and-just-audio-3cce17b4a7d?sk=0837a1b1773e27a4f879ff3072e90305) some day, but I'm not sure when that will happen.